# where does value custom field in DB

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, hook

i can create custom  filed in edit page product at tab general with below code in functions.php at theme :

```
// Display Fields
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields');
// Save Fields
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save');
function woocommerce_product_custom_fields()
{

    //Custom Product Number Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_custom_product_number_field',
            'placeholder' => 'Custom Product Number Field',
            'label' => __('Custom Product Number Field', 'woocommerce'),
            'type' => 'number',
            'custom_attributes' => array(
                'step' => 'any',
                'min' => '0'
            )   
        )
    );
}
function woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save($post_id)
{
// Custom Product Number Field
    $woocommerce_custom_product_number_field = $_POST['_custom_product_number_field'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_custom_product_number_field))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_product_number_field', esc_attr($woocommerce_custom_product_number_field));
}
```

just i don't know where does code save in DB ?
or how to save in custom table ?

Comment: _"i want to stored this code at table wp_wc_product_meta_lookup in DB Along with the rest of the product information"_ - 
that's wrong, the information, just like your code (which works by the way) is kept in the wp_postmeta table. 
That's how WooCommerce keeps track of product information, so why would you want to deviate from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code for it

```
<?php function product_add_meta_box( $post ){
    add_meta_box( 'product_meta_box', 'Custom Product Number Field', 'product_build_meta_box', 'product', 'side', 'low' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_product', 'product_add_meta_box' );

function product_build_meta_box( $post ){
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'product_meta_box_nonce' );
  $book_author = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_book_author', true); ?>
  <div class='inside'>
    <h3>Book Author</h3>
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="book_author" value="<?php echo $book_author; ?>" /> 
    </p>
  </div>
<?php }


function product_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ){

  if ( !isset( $_POST['food_meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['food_meta_box_nonce'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ){
    return;
  }

  if ( isset( $_REQUEST['book_author'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_book_author', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['book_author'] ) );
  }
}
add_action( 'save_post_product', 'product_save_meta_box_data', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: thanks a lot  but where does it save in DB

Comment: It will be save in post_meta table on respective post id